# Why the textfield is taking whole screen of a window in Java awt

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
public class myFrame extends Frame {

  myFrame(){
    TextField tf=new TextField(10);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,400);
    setTitle("myFrame");
    setBackground(Color.red);
    add(tf);

  }
public static void main(String[] args){
  myFrame f=new myFrame();

 }  
}
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgoy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Frame uses BorderLayout by default, and if you add a component to it in a "default" manner (without BorderLayout constraints) it will be added to the BorderLayout.CENTER position, taking up the whole of the Frame.

Possible solutions include using a different layout such as FlowLayout or even better, nesting components such as Panels that use their own layouts and adding your TextField to it.

Side issue: why use the AWT GUI library when it is more than 2 generations out of date?

For example, with Swing

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingExample extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

    public SwingExample() {
        // this is a JPanel that uses FlowLayout by default
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        add(textField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwingExample mainPanel = new SwingExample();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingExample"); // uses borderlayout
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // add jpanel to center position
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```